Get user info from google authentication in spring boot app
I have mixed REST/Views endpoints in spring boot app.
Also I have authentication/registration via google accounts.
I would like to get user details (email) after user signing up/in via google account.
But with config below, after signing up/in I can see from the logs that it redirects to http://localhost:8080/login/oauth2/code/google where it fetches additional info, but I do not understand how I can get it to register new user. Which bean/listener and how I should register to intercept that info?
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@Slf4j
public class WebSecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http
                .authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> auth.requestMatchers("/", "/index").permitAll())
                .anyRequest().authenticated()).oauth2Login(Customizer.withDefaults());


        return http.build();
    }

}

